# Is a Gaussian vector still a Gaussian vector when it is obtained by a linear transformation of dimension uplift?

Tags: linear-transformations, normal-distribution

Suppose $(X_1, X_2)$ is a Gaussian vector, then after applying transformation like [1 0;0 1;-1 -1] the outcome is still a Gaussian vector? Is it necessary for the transformation to have a generalized inverse?